# Handling loading popups with WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

I'm quite new with web automation but let's say I have understood basic and fundamental concepts (selector, DOM, xpath, ...) and even iFrame (an element can't be found if I'm not focused on the right iFrame).
I'm currently toying at work with a web based application, specifically developped by my company for its own purposes, so it's proprietary.
I succeeded in doing many things already but I'm struggling with the main problem of this app: loading. A lot of actions need accessing the database so I often have to wait for several seconds after clicking a button or submitting something.
The loading status is displayed by a kind of popup like this
[image]

Of course I could add an await browser.pause(xxxx) everytime but it's not an option since the loading duration is very variable. So I was thinking about finding that popup element and do a 1sec pause loop while it's still present. Good news is I have its Xpath. Bad news is I never seem to be able to detect it and attach it to a selector. So I'm guessing it probably doesn't belong to the main window frame but might be in a temporary iframe "floating" on top of the parent frame.. But I'm not sure, because when I'm inspecting the page code its DIV tag isn't embedded within an iframe tag

My question is: is there a way or a method to inspect and find out how to catch this element? Thank you, and sorry for my English

PS: I'm using Chrome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply call a `.waitForExist` or similar method on an element that comes after the loading screen. That way the testscript will wait for the page to get loaded and then continue.